# Можно ли "младше", или надо "моложе"?

Tags: словообразование

Вопрос. Можно ли "младше", или надо "моложе"?
Молодой - моложе - младший, степени (простая, сравнительная, превосходная) прилагательных. Так? Простая превосходная степень образуется при помощи:
1) суффиксов -айш, -ейш; 2), 3). Так пишут. В то же время форма "младше" считается допустимой. Так пишут.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос путанный (нет примеров, нет контекста), но попробую.

Тут скорее наоборот надо ставить вопрос, "когда возможно ***моложе***?". И таких случаев действительно немного.

Как правило универсальным языковым средством для передачи отношения сравнения старший/младший в прямом и переносном смысле служит именно "младше". 
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9

"Моложе" возможно только в прямом значении и только когда идет речь о сравнении фактического возраста - числа лет (месяцев, дней, веков) **от момента рождения** или, реже, возникновения чего-то. ***"Москва моложе Киева на четыре века"***. 
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9

Причем используется преимущественно в отношении живых людей и объектов, как бы подчеркивая потенциальную изменчивость сравниваемой характеристики. "Лермонтов был моложе Пушкина на 15 лет" - не звучит. Тут надо "младше".
(+)"не звучит" не потому, что "на 15 лет", а потому, что оба уже не стареют, окончив свой земной путь - нет точки сопоставления. Её, правда, можно как-то обозначить "В момент последней дуэли Лермонтов был моложе Пушкина на 9 лет" - так я ещё согласен.
(++) Ни о каких сравнениях двух чисел вообще речь не идет. Речь идет именно о возрасте. "Этот адрес младше на 80 байтов" - тут "моложе" неприменимо. "Майор младше полковника на два звания" - тут тоже. "Этот робот морально младше/моложе того станка" - тут даже не знаю, "оба хуже" ... Но главное даже не это, а то, что при использовании "моложе" возраст сравнивается не абстрактно, а для единого, зафиксированного момента времени. Для младше таких ограничений нет.
//===
Всё. Улучшать ответ без явной нужды больше не буду. Лучшее - враг хорошего.

Comment: "*Так как он **моложе всех**, то на него единогласно возлагают обязанность председательствовать в комициях.*" - "История Рима от основания Города", Тит Ливий. --- "*Неужели он **моложе меня**? – Не думаю.*" - "Жертва вечерняя", Петр Боборыкин ---- Вы не правы, что только если идёт речь о сравнении числа. Масса других примеров из литературы.

Comment: @oleedd - разве эти примеры что-то опровергают? Ну я уточнил формулировку.

Comment: Конечно, опровергают. "Моложе", наоборот, без чисел используется. Да и у вас нестыковка - вы сами об этом в конце говорите (что не звучит). Про Москву так нельзя сказать, там "младше" намного лучше.

Comment: Наоборот - это куда?! Послушайте, ну хоть немного наведите порядок в своих мыслях. Комментарии для того нужны, чтобы что-то уточнить, а не спорить так натужно. А вы еще и спорите сам с собой. Что именно опровергают ваши примеры? Какой мой тезис?!

Comment: Наоборот - без чисел. Что читать не умеете? Ладно... || Тезис - "Моложе" возможно только в прямом значении и только когда идет речь о сравнении фактического возраста - числа лет (месяцев, дней, веков). || Это больше про "младше".

Comment: Они совсем не опровергают. Вы хотите сказать, что в ваших примерах "моложе" используется в каком-то другом значении? Что речь идет не о физическом возрасте? Вот если бы вы мне привели пример типа "моложе душою" - тут еще можно было бы призадуматься... Впрочем, я даже этот пример видел изначально, но не стал специально оговаривать.

Comment: >Они совсем не опровергают. --- Они подтверждают то, что мне и так хорошо известно. Впрочем, и другим тоже. || Это хороший пример и известное выражение: хоть и стар внешне, но молод душой. || Кажись, этот вопрос совсем не о разнице двух слов...

Comment: Я не буду это комментировать. Пожалуйста, говорите по сути моего ответа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98004/discussion-between-behemothus-and-oleedd).

Comment: Что не понятного? "Младше" - сравнить 2 числа. "Моложе" - всё остальное.  В вашем ответе вы перепутали 2 слова местами. А всё остальное сходится... Вот последний пример уже отражает истину.

Comment: Я перепутал? да я таких формулировок и не употреблял. В чат, все в чат.

Answer (score 0):

Молодой = млад. (устаревшая сокращённая форма)

Моложе = младше. (при сравнении эта форма не является устаревшей)

Но стилистика (употребление) отличается:

`Младше` обычно используется для сравнения возраста двух субъектов (часто с цифрами).

*Вася **младше** Пети на 5 лет.*

`Моложе` часто используется по отношению к внешности, самочувствию (*выглядеть, чувствовать себя **моложе** на 10 лет*) или для общих сравнений без цифр (***моложе*** всех, *просто **моложе** кого-то*).

Примеры из литературы:

*Так как он **моложе всех**, то на него единогласно возлагают обязанность председательствовать в комициях.*

*Неужели он **моложе меня**? – Не думаю.*

Ответ: "младше" используется.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98018/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd------).

Answer (score 0):

**Моложе** = *ближе к возрасту молодости* (более молодой), чем тот, с кем сравнивают (один или оба сравниваемых полагаются относительно молодыми, сравнительная оценка степени "близости" субъективна и не всегда основывается на знании о возрасте).

**Младше** = *позже родившийся* (на месяц, год и т. п.) - объективная сравнительная оценка. В ряде формальных случаев: "*ниже по званию, статусу*".

> Из двух моих ныне здравствующих прадедов *младше* (не "моложе") тот, что
>   по материнской линии.

Вариант "моложе" в этом примере возможен только с сарказмом.